# Difference between an object and a dictionary?

Tags: actionscript, object, dictionary

What exactly is the difference between an object and a dictionary in Actionscript?

```
var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.something = "something";

var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
dict.something = "something";

trace(obj.something, dict.something);
```

The trace statement seems identical...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the example [here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) highlights at least one of the most significant differences, which is strict equality in comparing keys.

In summary, dictionary[key] does NOT necessarily return the same value as dictionary["key"], even if key.toString() equals "key".

However, object[key] will return the same value as object["key"], if key.toString() equals "key".

Comment: Is there an equivalent to Dictionary in JavaScript?

Comment: The example link no longer exists.

Answer (score 7):

Object() uses strings as keys, while Dictionary() uses objects as keys.

See http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_dictionary_.html